# jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.poc.consumingwebservice.wsdl.GetCountryRequest nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, soap, jaxb

Followed the link https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ to consume SOAP we  b service. it is working with spring boot 2.7.12 and java 11.
I have upgraded spring boot to 3.1.0 and java 11, it is throwing below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.poc.SpringWebServiceApplication.main(SpringWebServiceApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:958) ~[spring-oxm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:716) ~[spring-oxm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.marshal(MarshallingUtils.java:80) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$2.doWithMessage(WebServiceTemplate.java:399) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:569) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:539) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:391) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.poc.CountryClient.getCountry(CountryClient.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.poc.SpringWebServiceApplication.lambda$0(SpringWebServiceApplication.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.poc.consumingwebservice.wsdl.GetCountryRequest nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:543) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2 - d104f19]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:444) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2 - d104f19]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:265) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2 - d104f19]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:197) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2 - d104f19]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:712) ~[spring-oxm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
```

pom.xml files are

Working: spring boot 2.7.12 and java 11 pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-soap-consumer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-soap-consumer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java11</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>com.poc.consumingwebservice.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Not Working: spring boot 3.1.0 and java 17 pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-web-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <generatePackage>com.poc.consumingwebservice.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you generate your jaxb classes into `src/main/java` (`<generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>`)?

Comment: For the first time, I tried without adding <generateDirectory> tag in pom.xml. But getting the same error.

Comment: This is the example i am following for my application. https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-web-service/issues/57 how to add updated plugin jaxb to pom.xml ?

Comment: You should follow the complete examples: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-web-service/tree/main/complete

Comment: did you solve the issue? I'm facing the same on spring boot 3.1.1 and java 17